# Stream audio to DLNA TV from any Android app

Tags: android, audio, dlna

All [DLNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Living_Network_Alliance) stream apps that I can find use files from the phone or the cloud.

I want stream audio from another app, like with a Bluetooth audio system.

Is there an app for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AllStream](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kineticgamestudios.airtunes.android) does what you want I think.

Note that it **requires root access** (like all other applications that do this, it's needed to capture and "hijack" the device's audio stream)

Comment: Now AllStream stops every 20 minutes as demo version - maybe you know some free analog?